# How much time Salesforce takes to Review a lightning app before uploading that on AppExchange?

Tags: lightning-apps, appexchange, connected-apps, security-review

I am working on lightning app and want to upload that on AppExchange.
For this, I have followed the process described in Trailhead.

But I am not sure about how much time its takes in review of that package/application before uploading it on AppExchange.
My listing uploading status is:

[image]

Please guide me in this query.
Thank you

Comment: I see close votes that an answer would be opinion based. But an answer that reflects the actual time taken anytime in the last couple of months would be based on facts and useful to others entering the process.

Answer (score 5):

The security scan of the code is pretty quickly. From my past experience, the results are sent out within 1 hour of submitting for review.

Creating the false positive document and also fixing any code is the unknown entity here and the time to do this will depend on your code base.

Once you have submitted the false positives and the codebase for the actual review it can take 6-8 weeks for Salesforce to respond. If they fail your package then you get put in the queue again after you have addressed the issues. I would recommend setting a realistic timeline of 2-4 months to get a package through a security review, plus whatever time it takes for you to fix any issues the security review raises.